# how do i cast the void pointer to char array in a multithreaded program in C

Tags: c

how do i cast the void pointer to char array in a multithreaded program in C

```
void* write(void* ptr) {    
   char array[100];
   array= (char*)ptr;
   printf("%s",array);  
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with printf("%s", (char *)ptr); ?

Comment: arrays cannot be assigned. `char array[100];` is (except for `sizeof` purposes) the same as `const char* array = malloc(100* sizeof(char))`. Note the `const` modifier.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - you mean malloc (it's C, after all)

Comment: @Omar - I'm not sure what's the relevance of "multithreaded" here...

Comment: @SheetJS: Nothing: Doing `void* write(void* ptr) { printf("%s", (char *)ptr); };` would be the straight forward solution here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

You can cast it to a `char` *pointer*, however:

```
void* write(void* ptr){    
   char *array;
   array= (char*)ptr;
   printf("%s",array);  
}
```

Comment: No need to cast. Simply doing `array = ptr;` or `char * array = ptr;` would perfectly do. C "implicitly converts" to/from `void`-pointers.

Comment: True, albeit less instructive re: the confusion we’re addressing here.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use a pointer to a char array and not a fixed-size array.

```
void *ptr;
...
char *message;
message = (char *) ptr;
```

[Source](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)

Comment: Please also see this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038284/how-do-i-cast-the-void-pointer-to-char-array-in-a-multithreaded-program-in-c/19038325?noredirect=1#comment92524484_19038325